# I'm using flutter : is there a way with a mobile flutter app to launch another flutter app on another device

Tags: flutter, dart

I want, with my flutter app installed on my device, to launch an app on another device.
And share information if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean remote controlling another Device? Because starting an App on another Device is basically that and more OS related instead of App related. I guess with native Android its not impossible with deep understanding. But I don't see much chances with Flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from what I understood from you I can tell that you can't, the system restricts background possess you can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)